# detect the presence of a TrueCrypt volume inside a partition

Tags: partitioning, truecrypt

I don't remember if I have create a (not-hidden) TrueCrypt volume in one of my partitions and copied some files there. I've tried my usual password but it does not work. So, before reformatting such partition, I wish to know if there is a method to detect the presence of a TC volume in such partition.

I already know [TCHunt](https://github.com/stephenjudge/TCHunt) but it works only for files and folders, not partitions.

Comment: Recently a friend had a HD from his brother-in-law and it was described as "corrupted." We wound up mounting it using a linux VM and looking at the raw partition for clues. It actually said "truecrypt" in plain text...

Comment: @horatio The contents of any TrueCrypt volume (either a file-based volume or a partition-based one) are always just random bits.  There is no magic number or keyword anywhere in it that identifies it as a TrueCrypt volume.  If you saw the word "truecrypt" in the raw partition data, it was because it was stored in an ordinary file that was not encrypted in any way.

Comment: Nice assertion. The fact is, the owner tracked down the password and unencrypted the truecrypt volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy the raw partition data into a file and run TCHunt on that file.  On Linux, you can copy a partition to a file as user root with this command (assuming the partition you are copying is not mounted):

```
dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/tmp/myfile bs=512
```

Here, `/dev/sda3` is the partition being copied, and `/tmp/myfile` is the file that will contain the copy.

The same can be done for Windows, but I don't know how.  I would just boot the Windows box into a Linux live CD, mount a partition to hold the copy, and use the above `dd` command to read the (possibly) encrypted partition.